# asp.net webforms application make IE to crash

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have an application in asp.net web forms. It simple loads a excel file, convert it and download the converted file.

I works fine on any other browser (firefox, chrome, etc), however on IE (any version) it does not work.

I debugged in visual studio and no error is raised.

I disabled on add-ons/firewall/anti-virus.

Also on the browser (Inspect element - F12) it does not show any error.

I do not use a form, the page is a simple file upload and a button that reloads the page and on the code behind on page load it checks if there is file than process, else load the page.

So when I load the file and click submit, IE keeps thinking and thinking and goes anywhere.

Others browsers process instantly.

Is there any configuration or bug on IE that does not process it, what could be causing this to break/freeze?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Code behind

```
public partial class pgs_Import : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    GIFTS.BankAccount ourAccount = new GIFTS.BankAccount ("00", "0000", "00000", "00");
    ReportingDBDataContext db = new ReportingDBDataContext();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FUExpenses.HasFile)
        {
            DataTable dt = ImportData.ReadData(FUExpenses.PostedFile, ImportSource.Creditors);
            ProcessExpenses(dt, RBLType.SelectedValue);
        }
    }

    protected void ProcessExpenses(DataTable dt, string type)
    {
        string otherRef = "";
        string filePrefix = "";
        switch (type.ToUpper())
        {
            case "STAFFREIMBURSE":
                otherRef = "ReimburseExp";
                filePrefix = "StaffExpenses";
                break;
            case "ABCRENT":
                otherRef = "Rent";
                filePrefix = "Rent_";
                break;
            case "OTHER":
                otherRef = TxtOtherRef.Text;
                filePrefix = TxtOtherRef.Text.Replace(" ","_") + "_";
                break;
        }
        DateTime dueDate;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(TxtCalendar.Text, out dueDate))
        {
            if (CalExtender.SelectedDate.HasValue)
                dueDate = CalExtender.SelectedDate.Value;
            else
                dueDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        if (dueDate.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
            throw new Exception("Can't travel back in time.  Enter a date today or later.");

        //60 days is a limit enforced by BNZ
        if (dueDate.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(60).Date)
            throw new Exception("That's forward planning!  But can't be more than 60 days in future.");

        GIFTS.GIFTSCreditBatch batch = new GIFTS.GIFTSCreditBatch(ourAccount, dueDate, ChkBulk.Checked);
        List<string> problems = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
            try
            {
                GIFTS.GIFTSCreditRecordTransaction trans = new GIFTS.GIFTSCreditRecordTransaction();
                GIFTS.BankAccount acct = new GIFTS.BankAccount(row["Bank Branch"].ToString() + row["Account"].ToString());
                trans.OtherPartyAccountNumber = acct;
                decimal amt = Convert.ToDecimal(row["InvoiceAmount"]);
                amt = amt * 100;
                trans.TransactionAmount = Convert.ToInt32(amt);
                trans.TransactionCode = GIFTS.TransactionCodes.StandardCredit;
                trans.OtherPartyName = row["VendorID"].ToString();
                trans.OtherPartyReference = otherRef;
                trans.OtherPartyCode = row["Department"].ToString();
                trans.OtherPartyParticulars = row["Description"].ToString();
                trans.OriginatorName = "Company Name";
                trans.OriginatorCode = row["VendorID"].ToString();
                trans.OriginatorReference = row["Department"].ToString();
                trans.OriginatorParticulars = row["Description"].ToString();

                batch.Transactions.Add(trans);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //Don't add as a problem if the line is blank
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row["Bank Branch"].ToString()) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row["Account"].ToString()))
                    continue;

                problems.Add(String.Format("Row {0}: {1}", i + 2, exc.Message));
            }
        }

        if (problems.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (String problem in problems)
            {
                sb.Append(problem);
                sb.Append("<br />");
            }
            LblProblems.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            string fileName = String.Format("{0}{1}-{2}-{3}.afi", filePrefix, (dueDate.Year % 100), dueDate.Month, dueDate.Day);
            WriteOutput("text/plain", fileName, batch.ToCSV());
        }
    }

    protected void WriteOutput(string contentType, string fileName, string content)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.Write(content);
        Response.End();
    }
}

namespace GIFTS
{

    public enum TransactionCodes
    {
        StandardCredit = 50,
        Payroll = 52,
        Dividends = 61,
        UNDEFINED = -1
    }

    public static class HelperMethods
    {

        public static bool IsValidFileCreationDate(DateTime date)
        {
            if (date < DateTime.Now)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        public static bool IsValidFileDueDate(DateTime date)
        {
            if (date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) || date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(60))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For storing and formatting account numbers
    /// </summary>
    public interface IAccountNumber
    {
        string ToCondensedString();
        string ToExpandedString();
    }

    public class BankAccount : IAccountNumber
    {

        public string Bank { get; private set; }
        public string Branch { get; private set; }
        public string Account { get; private set; }
        public string Suffix { get; private set; }

        public BankAccount(string accountNumber)
        {
            ParseAccountNumber(accountNumber);
        }

        public BankAccount(string bank, string branch, string account, string suffix)
        {
            Bank = bank;
            Branch = branch;
            Account = account;
            Suffix = suffix;
        }

        public string ToCondensedString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Bank.PadLeft(2, '0'), Branch.PadLeft(4, '0'), Account.PadLeft(7, '0'), Suffix.PadLeft(3, '0'));
        }

        public string ToExpandedString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", Bank.PadLeft(2, '0'), Branch.PadLeft(4, '0'), Account.PadLeft(7, '0'), Suffix.PadLeft(3, '0'));
        }

        private void ParseAccountNumber(string accountNumber)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountNumber))
                throw new InvalidDataException("Blank account number");

            accountNumber = accountNumber.Replace("-", "");

            if (accountNumber.Length < 15 || accountNumber.Length > 16)
                throw new InvalidDataException(String.Format("Needs to be a 15 or 16 character string. {0} is {1} characters", accountNumber, accountNumber.Length));

            Bank = accountNumber.Substring(0, 2);
            Branch = accountNumber.Substring(2, 4);
            Account = accountNumber.Substring(6, 7);
            Suffix = accountNumber.Substring(13, accountNumber.Length - 13);
        }
    }

    public class CreditCardAccount : IAccountNumber
    {
        public string ToCondensedString()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string ToExpandedString()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class GIFTSCreditBatch
    {
        public const string FILETYPE = "7";
        public const string RECORDTYPEHEADER = "1";
        public const string RECORDTYPEFOOTER = "3";

        private DateTime fileCreationDate;
        private DateTime fileDueDate;
        private IAccountNumber originatorAccountNumber;

        public DateTime FileCreationDate
        {
            get { return fileCreationDate; }
            set { fileCreationDate = value; }
        }

        public DateTime FileDueDate
        {
            get { return fileDueDate; }
            set
            {
                if (HelperMethods.IsValidFileDueDate(value))
                    fileDueDate = value;
                else
                    throw new InvalidDataException("Not a valid File Due date");
            }
        }

        public IAccountNumber OriginatorAccountNumber
        {
            get { return originatorAccountNumber; }
            set { originatorAccountNumber = value; }
        }

        public bool AsBulkFile { get; set; }
        public List<GIFTSCreditRecordTransaction> Transactions { get; set; }

        public GIFTSCreditBatch(IAccountNumber ourAccount, DateTime dueDate, bool asBulkFile = false)
        {
            this.originatorAccountNumber = ourAccount;
            this.FileDueDate = dueDate;
            this.AsBulkFile = asBulkFile;
            FileCreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            Transactions = new List<GIFTSCreditRecordTransaction>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the hash total to use in the footer
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string CalcHash()
        {
            long hashTotal = 0;
            foreach (GIFTSCreditRecordTransaction trans in Transactions)
            {
                string subString = trans.OtherPartyAccountNumber.ToCondensedString().Substring(2, 11);
                long asNumber = Convert.ToInt64(subString);
                hashTotal += asNumber;
            }
            hashTotal = hashTotal % 100000000000;
            string hash = hashTotal.ToString();
            hash.PadLeft(11);

            return hash;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Outputs to a csv.
        /// Uses the AsBulkFile property to set the file mode
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A string with line breaks ready to be saved to file</returns>
        public string ToCSV()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(HeaderToCSV());
            foreach (GIFTSCreditRecordTransaction trans in Transactions)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(trans.ToCSV(AsBulkFile));
            }
            sb.AppendLine(FooterToCSV());
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string HeaderToCSV()
        {
            string blank = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(RECORDTYPEHEADER);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(blank);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(blank);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(blank);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(originatorAccountNumber.ToCondensedString());
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(FILETYPE);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(FileDueDate.ToString("yyMMdd"));
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(FileCreationDate.ToString("yyMMdd"));
            sb.Append(',');
            if (!AsBulkFile)
                sb.Append("I");
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string FooterToCSV()
        {
            int transactionAmountTotal = Transactions.Sum(t => t.TransactionAmount);
            int transactionRecordCount = Transactions.Count;
            string hashTotal = CalcHash();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(RECORDTYPEFOOTER);
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(transactionAmountTotal.ToString("000000000000"));
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(transactionRecordCount.ToString("000000"));
            sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(hashTotal.PadLeft(11, '0'));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class GIFTSCreditRecordTransaction
    {
        public const string RECORDTYPE = "2";

        private IAccountNumber otherPartyAccountNumber;
        private int transactionAmount;
        private string otherPartyName;
        private string otherPartyReference;
        private string otherPartyCode;
        private string otherPartyAlphaReference;
        private string otherPartyParticulars;
        private string originatorName;
        private string originatorCode;
        private string originatorReference;
        private string originatorParticulars;

        public IAccountNumber OtherPartyAccountNumber
        {
            get { return otherPartyAccountNumber; }
            set { otherPartyAccountNumber = value; }
        }
        public TransactionCodes TransactionCode;

        /// <summary>
        /// The amount in cents
        /// </summary>
        public int TransactionAmount
        {
            get { return transactionAmount; }
            set { transactionAmount = value; }
        }

        public string OtherPartyName
        {
            get { return otherPartyName; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 20)
                    otherPartyName = value.Substring(0, 20);
                else
                    otherPartyName = value;
            }
        }

        public string OtherPartyReference
        {
            get { return otherPartyReference; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 12)
                    otherPartyReference = value.Substring(0, 12);
                else
                    otherPartyReference = value;
            }
        }

        public string OtherPartyCode
        {
            get { return otherPartyCode; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 12)
                    otherPartyCode = value.Substring(0, 12);
                else
                    otherPartyCode = value;
            }
        }

        public string OtherPartyAlphaReference
        {
            get { return otherPartyAlphaReference; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 12)
                    otherPartyAlphaReference = value.Substring(0, 12);
                else
                    otherPartyAlphaReference = value;
            }
        }

        public string OtherPartyParticulars
        {
            get { return otherPartyParticulars; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 12)
                    otherPartyParticulars = value.Substring(0, 12);
                else
                    otherPartyParticulars = value;
            }
        }

        public string OriginatorName
        {
            get { return originatorName; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 20)
                    originatorName = value.Substring(0, 20);
                else
                    originatorName = value;
            }
        }

        public string OriginatorCode
        {
            get { return originatorCode; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 12)
                    originatorCode = value.Substring(0, 12);
                else
                    originatorCode = value;
            }
        }

        public string OriginatorReference
        {
            get { return originatorReference; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 12)
                    originatorReference = value.Substring(0, 12);
                else
                    originatorReference = value;
            }
        }

        public string OriginatorParticulars
        {
            get { return originatorParticulars; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length > 12)
                    originatorParticulars = value.Substring(0, 12);
                else
                    originatorParticulars = value;
            }
        }

        public string ToCSV(bool asBulkFile)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(RECORDTYPE);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OtherPartyAccountNumber.ToCondensedString());
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(((int)TransactionCode).ToString("00"));
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(TransactionAmount.ToString("000000000000"));
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OtherPartyName);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OtherPartyReference);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OtherPartyCode);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OtherPartyAlphaReference);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OtherPartyParticulars);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OriginatorName);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OriginatorCode);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(OriginatorReference);
            sb.Append(",");
            if (!asBulkFile)
                sb.Append(OriginatorParticulars);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post a repoducible set of code for this. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I see that you added code, but simply pasting all your code in isn't going to do it. Instead, read the link I provided above and provide a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I past the code just in case, but I am sure the problem isn't in the code. I debugged using fiddle and I can see it is returning the content as it is suppose to do, IE that is having problems to handle the content and give the download option. Others browser works fine. So my question is what could be causing the IE to not handle it?